# IIS7.5 Application is using web.config in the root directory instead of its own!

Tags: iis-7.5

Note: I did not setup a virtual directory its a Application!

Here is the structure

Hard drive folders:

```
-IISRoot
 -Webpage
  Test.aspx
  web.config

 -WebService
  -Bin
  Service.svc
  web.config
```

IIS is setup the following way:

```
-WebSite (Mapping against ISSRoot\Webpage)
 -Service ((Application) mapping against IISRoot\WebService)
```

Now when i try to run the Service.svc i get a error that a httpHandler was not found ("Could not load type 'Jympa.Nu.FileRequestHandler'")...

Now if i look in the web.config in the root there is a line adding this but the web.config in the webservice is not..

So why is IIS using the wrong web.config?

Edit:

> If i remove the web.config in the
>   Webpage folder the service works but
>   the webpage stops to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution i changed the pipeline mode on the application pool to Integrated.